# How to fix HDD (can't detect HDD in my BIOS)

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

I'm here to ask why can't I create a new partition when I tried to re-install my Windows OS(8.1)

Here's the detailed situation:

- I installed a game particularly a Visual Novel and to play it, I need to change my system locale to "Japanese(Japan). After the restart, it worked just fine. After a few minutes, I shut down my PC-- and when I tried to start it again, It now shows an error and restarts. And after it boots, it just shows a black screen.
- After a few loops, a message showed saying "The boot configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors."
- After that I created a Windows Installer in a bootable Flash Drive and booted it to my PC.
- There's a little problem to when booting my USB so I tried to disable all the boot options including the SATA.
- And then I booted it again and it worked.
- When I'm at the setup, I pressed the shift + F10 to use the command prompt.
- I clean my drive and then continue to the installation process.
- And then when I'm now trying to create a partition, a message saying that I can't create new partition. It says that I need to enable something in the BIOS may be my drive or something, and it also says something about UEFI.
- I've tried to go to the BIOS but when I entered, I can't see the SATA that I disabled earlier.

Please help me to fix this problem

### Update

While disassembling my CPU, I found ants in and around my HDD.

**Edit**

I tried something in my BIOS and I changed the setting from Onboard chips and then something like LAN PXE and enabled it and then when I'm installing windows a dialog box shows saying; "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu." I guess I really need to switch to Legacy IDE-- My current setting is in Native IDE

Comment: If the problem persists please write down the message or snap a picture and upload it. The actual message could have a lot of meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with HDD itself. 
Switch to legacy mode BIOS start up instead of UEFI and try to boot from this [live CD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) (you can burn it to a flash drive if you dont have DVD/CD, instruction how to do it on their website)

When it started, issue `startx` command.  When GUI desktop loaded, run from menu "Show filesystems", remember you HDD device (probable it whould be a `sda`), then from terminal issue following command:
`smartctl -a /dev/sda` (replace sda with your name from step above)
In table of attributes of HDD check parameters 5, 196, 197, if its value greater than 0, then HDD is failing. If it is not then run `gparted` (it is in taskbar) and remove any partitions on your HDD and try windows installation again.

P.S.

> I don't get it. Please explain it more clearly. . .

Any HDD/SSD has its own "computer" inside. `smartctl` program talk directly to HDD/SSD and asking to show internal state of [S.M.A.R.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes.
Take a look at [S.M.A.R.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) to understand what that parameters means.
Most dangerous attributes are 5,196,197 which show physical state of hard drive's plates. If it get failed(attribute's value are greater than zero) usually you can't do anything about it(Well, it can be repaired in some cases, but the cost will be greater than if you get a new HDD ). Since you told that HDD isn't visible even in BIOS then it could be an issue with HDD that's why I suggest you to check it. If SystemResqueCD can't see your HDD, then most likely it is an issue with electronic board of HDD. If you give a time to cool down HDD completely(turn computer off) and after that HDD will appear again in BIOS and disappear after some time again then it is an issue with HDD board for sure(it happens usually when HDD was overheated due to high computer loading while you play games or use heavy calculation programs).

If all attributes of HDD are Ok (zero) than it can be boot area of HDD were corrupted(malware or incorrect using low level software tools or copyright protection from some programs) that messed up data on HDD such way it can't be recognized. `Gparted` program I wrote above can wipe out completely info about partitions, so windows install will see HDD as completely brand new HDD

Comment: Here is short guide http://www.ghacks.net/2012/03/19/system-rescue-cd-windows-repair-and-recovery-tool-collection/  It pretty intuitive tool, make a right click on partitions and choose delete